# Angular post ImageData to Spring Backend and save as jpeg

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I am currently trying to offer my users a possibility to choose, edit and upload an image. My ImageEditor (https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/bootstrap5/image-editor/default) gives me the edited image as a  [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) type.

I transformed the ImageData into a Base64 data string which contains my image.

I send this string as formdata via http post to my Backend where I try to receive it as a MultiPart File. But it is allways null.

Angular component:

```
  beforeSave(args: any): void {
    const imageEditor: ImageEditorComponent = getComponent(document.getElementById('image-editor')!, 'image-editor');

    args.cancel = true;

    // Custom save logic goes here
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = imageEditor.getImageData().width;
    canvas.height = imageEditor.getImageData().height;
    ctx!.putImageData(imageEditor.getImageData(), 0, 0);

    const image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();

    this.learningContentService.saveImageInTempLocation(image.src,"temp", args.fileType).subscribe(res => console.warn(res))
```

Angular service:

```
saveImageInTempLocation(image: any, imageName: string, imageFormat: string): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image);

    return this.http.post<string>(
      `${this.resourceUrl}/save-image?imageName=${imageName}&imageFormat=${imageFormat}`, formData,
      { observe: 'response' }
    );
  }
```

Spring Controller

```
@PostMapping(path="/save-image",consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveImageForLearningContent(
        @RequestBody MultipartFile image
    ) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
```